# What is the role of your advisor and other lab members in your research work?

Tags: phd, advisor

I have a very simple question : how involved should a Ph.D. advisor be in the work of a Ph.D. student ?
Should he / she be correcting the work assigned to the student after few days / weeks of student's work, won't they check anything for simulations outputs for example ? or should they be saying few guiding words and it's up to the student to write code, simulate and write the paper ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think there is a universal answer. Different advisers have different styles.  I look over the code that my students write and offer suggestions on how to improve it (and sometimes do it myself); my students like that. My adviser did not have any significant programming skills despite being in computational mathematics, and was mostly hands-off -- but I think he was an excellent adviser anyway.

In the end, different students need different advising styles, and one of the things I have learned advising 8 graduate students so far is this: what works with one student does not work for another one. I suspect one could also turn this around and say from the perspective of the student: The style of one professor may work for them, whereas the style of another may not.

Comment: +1 another important factor is the stage of the student. A beginning student will likely need more involvement from the supervisor than one who is close to completion.

Comment: Other thing is that the advisor should provide adequate environment for the Ph.D. student to succeed (he could then be less involved if the lab members cooperate with the Ph.D. student and help him/her especially for a starting student like @astronat pointed out.)

Comment: Also how could a student know if he / she did right or wrong the task, there should be a validation performed by the advisor or some lab member

Answer (score 6):

The goal of a PhD is to make *you* better at research, ready to take up a research position later. So, regarding the advisor, he should be:

- Someone with vast knowledge on your field of research, who knows what is right and wrong, what are the techniques and tools, the latest developments and so on;
- Someone that *stimulates* you to come up with your own ideas;
- Someone who can supervise your work and ideas and see if you're on a good path or if you should be doing something differently.
- Someone (ideally) who adapts to your style in a way: some students need more supervising and to discuss quite often, some do not.
- Someone who motivates you to use the scientific method and report relevant conclusions, even when they do not please you.

Your advisor should not:

- Micromanage you, following every single step;
- Tell you exactly what to do. Don't forget a PhD is a research job, so neither you or your advisor will always have the answers; however, if it's always your advisor telling you what to do, you're not a PhD student, but a technician.

There must also be a mutual trust between you two. If the advisor knows you and your technical capabilities, he won't need to correct every line of code you write, only the results coming from it (unless your thesis is about the coding itself).